# Rsyslog omprog pass message to scripts

Tags: rsyslog, clsidfromprogid

Accurately, I want to filter logs and send some warning email.

Firstly, I tried **ommail**, but unfortunately, this module only support mail server which do not need authentication, but my mail server needs.

So I tried to use **omprog**, I wrote a python script to logon to my mail server, it will recieve one parameter which is the log and send it as mail body.
Then I got the problem, I cannot pass the log to my script, if I try like this, $msg will be recognized as a string .

```
if $fromhost-ip == "x.x.x.x" then {
    action(type="omprog"
            binary="/usr/bin/python3 /home/elancao/Python/sendmail.py $msg")
}
```

I tried to search the [official doc](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html).

```
module(load="omprog")
action(type="omprog"
   binary="/path/to/log.sh p1 p2 --param3=\"value 3\""
   template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
```

but in the sample, what they are using is a string "p1", not a dynamic parameter.

Can you please help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected use of omprog is for your program to read stdin and there it will find the full default `RSYSLOG_FileFormat` template data (with date, host, tag, msg).  This is useful, as it means you can write your program so that it is started only once, and then it can loop and handle all messages as they arrive.

This cuts down on the overhead of restarting your program for each message, and makes it react faster. However, if you prefer, your program can exit after reading one line, and then rsyslog will restart it for the next message. (You may want to implement `confirmMessages=on`).

If you just want the `msg` part as data, you can use `template=...` in the action to specify your own minimal template.

If you really must have the msg as an argument, you can use the legacy filter syntax:

```
^program;template
```

This will run `program` once for each message, passing it as argument the output of the template. This is [not recommended](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/actions.html).

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if omprog script is not doing or not saving to a file the problem is that :

1. rsyslog is sending the full message to that script so you need to define or use a template
2. your script needs to listen to  and return an

example in perl whit omprog

#my $input = join( '-', @ARGV ); ///not working I lost 5 hours of my life

my $input = ;  now this is what you need

Hope this what the perl/python/rsyslog community needs.

Comment: Heros make the world better...❤